# Explicit expression for $1/e$ as a limit

Tags: calculus, limits, logarithms

I am following an elementary math book: [What is Mathematics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0195105192) and currently referring to infinite series representation of the exponent.

In deriving the explicit formula for $e$ and $1/e$, the author exploits the derivative of the log function (see attached screenshots).

I am clear till the point $e^z$ is defined as $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+z/n)^n$.
After this, the author substitutes $z$ as $1$ and $-1$ to get expansions for $e$ and $1/e$.

Here, I'm not able to understand why its okay to take $z$ as $-1$

The way I see it, $z$ equals $1/x$ (screenshot 2) and $1/x$ cannot be negative because it's the derivative of the log (monotonically increasing function)

Additional notes:

The author has defined the log function as integral(1/u)du from 1 to x. (Screenshot 3)

He then proceeds to define the exponent as an inverse operation to this 'newly discovered' log function (allowed because in the range defined (0,infinity), log is a monotonically increasing continuous function)

And only then proceeds with the argument above.

Hence, I wonder how could we take z = -1. Wouldn't it imply 1/x = -1 i.e x = -1 which is outside the defined domain for logx?

If we rather take the function as log|x|, that opens the question, how do we define log|x| as an integral? (similar to the author's approach)

How do we define the inverse of log|x| (not 1-1)?

What am I missing here?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any $z$ you can define $E(z)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac zn\right)^n$. The cited argument shows that $E(z)=\exp(z)$ for positive $z$, where $\exp$ is the inverse function of $\ln$. In the cited pages it is not shown that $\exp$ is an exponential function, so that writing $\exp(z)=e^z$ is not really justified. For that one would need to show that the functional equation $E(x)E(y)=E(x+y)$ is satisfied, and that $E$ is a continuous function (some rather weak formulations are possible).

For any real number $z$ you get, for sufficiently large $n$,
$$
\left(1+\frac zn\right)^n\left(1-\frac zn\right)^n
=
\left(1-\frac{z^2}{n^2}\right)^n\in\left[1-\frac{z^2}n,\,1\right]
$$
the last using the Bernoulli inequality $(1+a)^n\ge 1+an$ for $a\ge -1$. From this follows
$$
E(z)E(-z)=1\implies E(-z)=E(z)^{-1}.
$$

This allows to extend the identification $E(z)=\exp(z)=e^z$ also to negative $z$.

Comment: Okay. So what I understand from your answer is that the author divides the answer in two parts. Part one uses the original deduction to find an expression for e^x (x>= 0)
Then we use your suggested formula to find for negative values of x.
Is that what you're trying to say?

Comment: No, as you observed, the author really left a gap in his reasoning. My answer, as the other answers, are about relatively easy ways to fill this gap, to extend the limit formula to negative $x$.

Comment: Got it! Thanks LutzL!

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\log\lvert x\rvert$ is differentiable in $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ and if you differentiate it, you get $\frac1x$. So, yes, you can take negative values for $x$.

Comment: Hi José, thanks for the answer. 
To give further background, the author introduces and defines logx as Integral(1/u)du from 1 to x.
From this point he proceeds to define the exponent as the inverse operation (valid only because logx defined in the interval 0 to infinity and monotonically increasing) 
I maybe wrong, but wouldn't under such constructions, the above device to use log|x| fall outside the scope of the argument he proceeds with?
Did my comment make sense?

Comment: Your comment makes perfectly sense and cannot understand how such an error can be found in a classical text such as this one.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that

$$1-\frac1n=\frac1{\dfrac n{n-1}}=\frac1{1+\dfrac1{n-1}}.$$

Then raising to the power $n$ or $n-1$ makes no difference (the factor tends to $1$) and

$$f(-1,n)=\frac1{f(1,n)}$$ in the limit.

Comment: So you're saying that 1/e is f(-1,n), correct? (As per your notations)
As per my question, I do not question the result. I just want a justification of that key step when the author puts z = -1 because such a substitution appears 'magical' i.e I can't tie it to some logical step.

Comment: @hargun3045 I am precisely discussing the case of $z=-1$.

Comment: Okay. So you mean if limn->(infinity) (1+1/n)^n = e (as I fully agree to the previous steps), your rearrangement gives us lim(1-1/n)^n = 1/e which is e^-1. Have I understood what you're trying to say?

Comment: @hargun3045: I am saying that if $\lim =e$ for $z=1$, then $\lim =1/e$ for $z=-1$.

Comment: Thanks for the swift response. 
I imagine I get your reasoning. 
I am just not getting it how we can take z as -1. Wouldn't it be like outside the domain of what we defined?
The author clearly defines the log for positive x only. (screenshot 3 in my post)
Our manipulations gets a reasonable result but how do we justify putting in negative values of x ?(x and z are related as z = 1/x)
Do we proceed as suggested by LutzL "This implies that indeed −=lim→∞(1+−), even if originally the exponential was only defined/identified as this limit for positive arguments"

Comment: @hargun3045: if you set $z=-1$ in $(1+z/n)^n$, you obtain $(1-1/n)^n$, don't you ? There are no restrictions on the argument of the exponential. But where do you see $z=1/x$ ??

Comment: In screenshot 2, The author says " By writing z = 1/x and using again the laws of logarithms we obtain" and then proceeds to the infinite limit expression for e^z

Comment: @hargun3045: (12) and (13) are independent of the previous equation with $\log x$.